# ES Lint firing up for SetStateAction in a typescript interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, react-typescript

I have a component as follows.

```
import React, { SetStateAction } from 'react';

interface ColorObject {
  name: string,
  slug: string,
  hex: string,
}

interface Props {
  color: ColorObject
  onClick: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<ColorObject>>,
}

const Color: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { color, onClick } = props;
  const selectColor = () => {
    onClick(color);
  };
  return (
    <button type="button" className="color" onClick={selectColor}>
      <div className="block" style={{ backgroundColor: color.hex }} />
      <p className="color-label">{color.name}</p>
    </button>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Color);
```

Everything works fine but the `SetStateAction` lights in red at the import statement with the following error.

> 'SetStateAction' is defined but never used. eslint(no-unused-vars)

However as you can see I am using it in the Props interface. How can i overcome this without replacing the `SetStateAction` with `React.SetStateAction` in the mentioned interface.

Below is my .eslintrc.json file.

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                "extensions": [
                    ".tsx",
                    ".ts"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "ignorePackages",
            {
                "js": "never",
                "mjs": "never",
                "jsx": "never",
                "ts": "never",
                "tsx": "never"
            }
        ],
        "react/prop-types": 0
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [
                    ".js",
                    ".jsx",
                    ".ts",
                    ".tsx"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the eslint --init and chose the airbnb style guide. Chose typescript in the selection as well.

Comment: Can you post your ESLint config?

Comment: It could be related to not using `eslint-plugin-react`: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/941

Comment: @RobertCooper I used eslint --init and selected the airbnb style guide. chose typescript as well. I have updated the question with the config details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add something like this to the rules?

```
"no-unused-vars": "off",
"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"]
```

you can find the options [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#options)

Comment: I actually need that rule because it is helpful in keeping the code base clean. So using that exception is not the ideal fix.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the intent of the config change. This change doesn't disable `no-unused-vars` entirely - it instead switches to use a rule that understand typescript code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `eslint-config-airbnb`, consider using `eslint-config-airbnb-typescript`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript

The base airbnb config is built for pure JS code, and does not enable rules that understand typescript.

If you want to keep using that config, you will have to make manual tweaks to your config locally like the one mentioned by @Sgh.